# Adding Google map canvas dropdown

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

How can I add a

```
<select>
<option>a</option>
<option>a</option>
</select>
```

inside map canvas?? Please help me. I want this dropdown after drag and drop marker in map view

Answer (score 0):

Any element can be placed over `canvas` element with **`absolute`** positioning.

```
select {
 position: absolute;
 z-index: 1;
 left: 20px;
 top: 20px; 
}
```

I have created a sample [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/praveen_jegan/7F99q/3/) to show it will work.